# Hibernal HQL is returning only one row

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Below is the HQL query I'm using :

```
Session ssn=HibernateSessionFactory.openSession();  
Query query = ssn.createQuery("from TUIDInfo e where  e.id = :cred_id  ");              
query.setParameter("cred_id",cred_id);
List list = query.list();
```

My table contains around 20 entries matching the `cred_id` but this query only returns the last row in the table. Why is this so ? The `query.list().size()` attribute is always 1 even though there are lot more entries.

Comment: are you sure to be wanting to query on e.id?  Can you do the same query using sql?

Comment: I'm so sorry. I was mapping the wrong attributes. It should have been `e.cred_id = cred_id` . Now it works.

Comment: great, maybe you can mark my comment as useful then